# How is the Firebase token passed to the redirect url after FirebaseUI login is complete?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I'm using the web version of the FirebaseUI.

I've been able to set everything up so that a user can log in and I get a authResult object back from Firebase. From that authResult I can get the user id and Token.

My question:
Once I get that object, how do I pass the Token details to either the redirecturl or to another web page?

Is it all done via parameters or should the Token (which I believe is JWT) be passed in as a header?

I've read large parts of the docs but this step always seem implied and is not explicitly spelled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your application. Firebase Auth will persist the user via `indexedDB`/`localStorage` on the same origin. `onAuthStateChanged` will trigger with the signed in user on any page of the same origin.
If you are using your own backend server, you need to pass the ID token to your backend and [verify it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).

How you pass it depends on your application/system. SPA apps append it with every XHR request (either via header or POST body). Other applications, set the ID token as a cookie and setup proactive token refresh every hour on expiration to update the cookie with a new ID token. Other applications exchange the ID token with some other session cookie management solution like session/expressjs in the case of node.js, or you can use [session cookie management provided by firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies), etc.

Comment: When it comes to the persistence by Firebase Auth, where exactly is it being persisted?

I noticed that after a redirect from the successful sign in call back, the firebase library can still read the token so I assume somewhere in the browser but I'm not sure on the exact mechanism.

Comment: The user is persisted via `indexedDB`/`localStorage`. If you redirect to another page of the same origin, `onAuthStateChanged` will trigger with the signed in user.

Comment: Thanks! That wasn't entirely clear from the docs and examples.

@bojeil do you mind if I edit your answer with that as well?

Comment: I have added my comment to the answer.